# Android optimization NDK function vs Java final boolean

Tags: java, android, compiler-optimization, javac, jit

I have some logging code that should only work for internal builds and I have logic in my NDK C++ to make the decision whether this is an internal build:

```
native boolean isInternalBuild();

void log() {
    if (isInternalBuild()) {
        Log.d("LOG", "Log this: " + someLogicToComputeLog());
    }
}
```

Would the Java compiler or JIT be able to optimize it out in case I switch to a Java final boolean or would it perform about the same:

```
static final boolean INTERNAL_BUILD = false; // or true in case this is an internal build

void log() {
    if (INTERNAL_BUILD) {
        Log.d("LOG", "Log this: " + someLogicToComputeLog());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimizing away the test in the first case is almost certainly beyond the capabilities of a JIT compiler.

In the second case, it is likely (but not guaranteed<sup>1</sup>) that the Java compiler will optimize away the `if` statement when the expression is a *compile-time constant expression* that evaluates to `false`.  This "conditional compilation" feature is described in [JLS 14.21](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) (at the end of the section).

The caveats are:

- this feature only works with `if` statements, and
- it only works when testing a (compile time) *constant expression* in the sense of [JLS 15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

Since this optimization is *typically* done by the Java bytecode compiler, you can easily confirm that it is being done by *your* compiler by using `javap` to examine the bytecodes.

---

<sup>1 - The JLS text says: *"An optimizing compiler ... **may** choose to omit the code for that statement from the generated class file ..."*.  It is not technically required to do this.</sup>